# Insert mutiple table in 1 query using express

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I get an error that is different from what it should be and i have tried this query in heidi mysql and its work but why in express is not working?

I got error like this :

```
code: "ER_PARSE_ERROR"
errno: 1064
index: 0
sql: "INSERT INTO products set `name` = 'faris d', `slug` = '', `description` = '<p>asdasddsa</p>', `regular_price` = 55555 ;↵                  INSERT INTO product_category set product_id = (SELECT id  from products as p order by p.id desc limit 1), category_id = 2;↵           ↵               "
sqlMessage: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERT INTO product_category set product_id = (SELECT id  from products as p ord' at line 2"
sqlState: "42000"
```

**assume i have data like this :**

```
product:{
description: "<p>asdasddsa</p>"
name: "faris d"
regular_price: 55555
slug: ""
}

product_category:{
description: "AXAS"
label: "SWEATSHIRT"
value: 2
}
```

I want to insert data into a table product and product_category with 1 query.

on the product there is an id where the primary key is related to product_category.

**Product Table**

```
   Product
-id
-name
-slug
-description
-regular_price
```

**Product_category Table**

```
   Product_category
-id
-product_id
-category_id
```

**and this is my code :**

```
   let sql = `INSERT INTO products set ? ;
                  INSERT INTO product_category set product_id = (SELECT id  from products as p order by p.id desc limit 1), category_id = ?;

               `;
    db.query(sql, [req.body.product, req.body.product_category.value],(err,results)=>{
        if (err) return res.status(400).json(err);
        return res.status(200).json(results);
    })
```

actually I'm still a beginner using mysql on express. so please let me know what is wrong with my code.

Comment: You can't do multi query (https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#executing-queries-in-parallel)

But I think you just want the last inserted id from the first query, look here : https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#getting-the-id-of-an-inserted-row

Comment: What the comment above said; many database apis do not allow multiple queries in one "execute".

Comment: is there other better ways to do that? @Uueerdo

Comment: Assuming the insert was to a table with an auto-incremented id field, [last_insert_id()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/getting-unique-id.html) is usually used (either immediately following or queried for when repeated use is needed). Some apis automatically include the id in the "result" of the insert, but that varies from one api to the next, and I am unfamiliar with the ones used in javascript.

Comment: but if I use that method, when there is one query that is wrong or there is invalid data it will be messed up. Am I wrong? @Uueerdo

Comment: I am not familiar with the particulars of javascript, but you should be able to catch errors from earlier queries, to avoid continuing under the assumption that everything is ok.